# C++ Builder 11 64-Bit build fails linking to WBEMUUID.A - No symbols in its dictionary

Tags: c++builder

I switched from 32-bit to 64-bit platform, it completed until link which resulted in:

> [ilink64 Error] Fatal: Archive file 'C:\PROGRAM FILES
> (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\22.0\LIB\WIN64\RELEASE\PSDK\WBEMUUID.A' lists
> no symbols in its dictionary.

Is this a bug or is there something else I'm supposed to do?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your code has following line:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid")
```

In C++ Builder, this is not needed to use the interface. You can simply remove the line.

[Source](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41556):

> We do not need those libraries to use the interfaces, the MS compilers emit symbols for the GUIDs into those libraries, and their linker then use those GUIDs, hence all their examples show linking those libraries in.